# Android - first tab is not loading at first

Tags: android, tabs

I have added tabs dynamically. Alaways my first tab is loaded only after going and coming back from someother tab. Could you please suggest me a solution to overcome this problem.

//------------ Add the tabs dynamically

```
    for (int i=0; i<tabs.length; i++){
        String tabName = tabs[i];
        specs = th.newTabSpec(tabName);
        specs.setContent(R.id.llItemList);
        list1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvCommonList);
        adapter=new Adapter(this, item[i]); 
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);
        specs.setIndicator(tabName);
        th.addTab(specs);
    }   

public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       currentTab =  tabId; 
         for (int i=0; i<tabs.length; i++){
        if (currentTab.equals(tabs[i])){ 
            linearLayout.removeView(list1);
            linearLayout.addView(list1);
            adapter=new Adapter(this, item[i]);  
            list1.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```